# Are colons allowed in URLs?

Tags: apache, uri, standards

I thought using colons in URIs was "illegal". Then I saw that vimeo.com is using URIs like `http://www.vimeo.com/tag:sample.`

1. What do you feel about the usage of colons in URIs?
2. How do I make my Apache server work with the "colon" syntax because now it's throwing the "Access forbidden!" error when there is a colon in the first segment of the URI?

Comment: For reference, colons don't seem to be specifically disallowed at that point by RFC2396 section 3.3 http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

Comment: can you give production url which has colon ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Colons are allowed in the URI path. But you need to be careful when writing relative URI paths with a colon since it is not allowed when used like this:

```
<a href="tag:sample">
```

In this case `tag` would be interpreted as the URI’s scheme. Instead you need to write it like this:

```
<a href="./tag:sample">
```

Answer (score 15):

> Are colons allowed in URLs?

### Yes, unless it's in the first path segment of a relative-path reference

So for example you can have a URL like this:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Welcome

And you can use it normally as an absolute URL or some relative variants:

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Welcome">Welcome Template</a>
<a href="/wiki/Template:Welcome">Welcome Template</a>
<a href="wiki/Template:Welcome">Welcome Template</a>
```

But this would be invalid:

```
<a href="Template:Welcome">Welcome Template</a>
```

because the "Template" here would be mistaken for the protocol scheme.
You would have to use:

```
<a href="./Template:Welcome">Welcome Template</a>
```

to use a relative link from a page on the same level in the hierarchy.

### The spec

See the RFC 3986, Section 3.3:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3

> The path component contains data, usually organized in hierarchical
> form, that, along with data in the non-hierarchical query component
> (Section 3.4), serves to identify a resource within the scope of the
> URI's scheme and naming authority (if any).  The path is terminated
> by the first question mark ("?") or number sign ("#") character, or
> by the end of the URI.

> If a URI contains an authority component, then the path component
> must either be empty or begin with a slash ("/") character.  If a URI
> does not contain an authority component, then the path cannot begin
> with two slash characters ("//").  **In addition, a URI reference
> (Section 4.1) may be a relative-path reference, in which case the
> first path segment cannot contain a colon (":") character.**  The ABNF
> requires five separate rules to disambiguate these cases, only one of
> which will match the path substring within a given URI reference.  We
> use the generic term "path component" to describe the URI substring
> matched by the parser to one of these rules. [emphasis added]

Example URL that uses a colon:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Welcome

Answer (score 10):

Also note [the difference between Apache on Linux and Windows](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk:Short_URL/Archive_1#Colon_issue_with_Very_Short_URLs_on_Windows). Apache on Windows somehow doesn't allow colons to be used in the first part of the URL. Linux has no problem with this, however.