# How to get a url as a param in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**CODE:**

```
app.get("/:url", function(req,res) {
    var url = req.params.url;
    res.send(url);
});
```

---

**PROBLEM:**

This does not work.

If I try:

```
http://localhost:3000/https://www.google.com
```

I get:

```
Cannot GET /https://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, using a regex:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.get(/^\/(.*)/, function (req, res) {

    var url = req.params[0];
    res.send(url);

});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on 3000'));
```

When you run:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/https://www.google.com
```

the server should return:

```
https://www.google.com
```

### Update

There is some controversy whether or not colons are legal in URLs.

See this question for details:

- **[Are colons allowed in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737575/are-colons-allowed-in-urls/43283492#43283492)**

According to RFC 3986 this is a legal URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986
```

But note that while this is legal as well:

```
http://localhost:3000/https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3
```

if you entered that URL in the browser, your server would only get:

```
/https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986
```

in the request. For that reason while not strictly necessary I would still recommend URL-encoding the URL that you put in other URLs - see the answer by **Zac Delventhal**.

### Experiment

Using the above code example, this command:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/https://www.google.com/
```

will output this:

```
https://www.google.com/
```

But this command:

```
curl 'http://localhost:3000/https://www.google.com/#fragment'
```

will output this:

```
https://www.google.com/
```

Note that I used single quotes above not because they are necessary here - they're not, see this:

```
echo http://localhost:3000/https://www.google.com/#fragment
```

but to show that the hash fragment doesn't disappear because it is treated as a comment by the shell in case anyone thought that that could be the reason. It is not sent even when the quotes are used, and what happens can be demonstrated with the `-v` switch of `curl`:

```
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /https://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
```

As you can see the hash fragment is not even sent with HTTP so it is impossible for your server to know even that it existed.

Incidentally, this also demonstrates that using un-encoded URL within other URLs would not mess up any proxy, because HTTP requests to the proxy servers send this:

```
GET https://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

and not this:

```
GET /https://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

so they cannot be confused. (Note the slash.)

Comment: @Coder1000 - You may want to know that I don't think `http://localhost:3000/https://www.google.com` is a legal URL so there could be some infrastructure (such as proxies) that it might not work with if they are expecting a URL that follows the rules.

Comment: @jfriend00 Actually both the colon and the slash are legal in URLs. For example see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Welcome

Comment: Do you care to show a specification reference that says `http://localhost:3000/https://www.google.com` is a legal URL?  Working examples don't prove they follow a specification.  Lots of things happen to work that are illegal vs. a specification.

Comment: Here's a counter example.  On the Google search page, all the search result links are Google redirect links (so they can track what you click on) and contain the actual URL as a parameter to the URL in the search page (right-click and do copy link to get the actual link).  Google encodes both `:` and `/` in those.  Why would they do that if it was not a better or safer way of doing things?

Comment: @jfriend00 I assume we're talking about the colon here because obviously slashes and dots are legal in URLs. See the [RFC 3986, Section 3.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3). You can't use a colon in a relative URL (which this isn't) and even then only in the first part segment. There are some questions here about it on Stack Overflow and Quora as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737575/are-colons-allowed-in-urls ; https://www.quora.com/Is-it-safe-to-use-a-colon-in-the-path-of-a-URL

Comment: @jfriend00 You're not saying that slashes are illegal in URLs, do you. ;) I assume that Google encodes them so that the entire URL is in one part of the URL. I'm not saying that you cannot encode those characters, I'm not even saying that not encoding them is better. I'm just saying that it's legal, that's all. And by the way, I remember when google used URLs like `http://www.google.com/*/http://www.example.com/` for redirects years ago. (with an asterisk and not-encoded URL) (by the way: in my previous comment it should be "path segment" and not "part segment")

Answer (score 2):

That's because `:` and `/` are special characters used in constructing a URL. In other words, they are are not *url-safe*. If you want to send those characters as part of a URL path, using the default Express param parser, you have to [percent-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) them.

Try this with your existing code:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
```

You should get back:

```
https://www.google.com
```

Another option would be to use a query parameter instead of a path variable. Modify your code snippet slightly to this:

```
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    var url = req.query.url;
    res.send(url);
});
```

Then, you can test it with this command:

```
curl http://localhost:3000?url=https://www.google.com
```

And you should get back:

```
https://www.google.com
```

Though I would say it is still probably a good idea to percent-encode those characters, even though Express can parse them fine this way. It could potentially lead to weird behavior down the road.

Still another option would be to send the url as a string in the body of a `POST` request, but that may not be RESTful depending on your use case.