# python urllib.parse.urljoin on path starting with numbers and colon

Tags: python, url, urllib

Excuse me, what the heck?

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> base = 'http://example.com'
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin(base, 'abc:123')
'http://example.com/abc:123'
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin(base, '123:abc')
'123:abc'
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin(base + '/', './123:abc')
'http://example.com/123:abc'
```

*python3.7* documentation says:

> Changed in version 3.5: Behaviour updated to match the semantics defined in RFC 3986.

Which part of that RFC enforces such madness, and whether it should be considered a bug?

Comment: That does indeed look like a bug to me. RFC 3986 states *"Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters beginning with a letter"*, which `123` clearly does not and thus isn't a valid scheme. So, as far as I can tell, `urllib.parse.urljoin(base, '123:abc')` should actually return `'http://example.com/123:abc'` and `urllib.parse.urljoin(base, 'abc:123')` should return `'abc:123'`. But then again, while that's a valid URI, it's not a valid URL...

Comment: @gdlmx specifically, Python 3.7.2

Comment: getting the same with 2.7.15 as well

Comment: I have tested in `3.7.2` and got this behavior. But the last line in your post is wrong: `'http://example.com/path/123:abc'`.

Comment: @gdlmx fixed the last line.  Indeed, I've played with it for a while and basically forgot to strip the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Which part of that RFC enforces such madness?

This behavior is *correct* and *consistent* with other implementations, as indicated by [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2):

> A path segment that contains a colon character (e.g., "this:that") cannot be used as the first segment of a *relative-path reference*, as it would be mistaken for a scheme name.  Such a segment *must be preceded by a dot-segment (e.g., "./this:that")* to make a relative-path reference.

It's been already discussed in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1737589/6238076):

> Colons are allowed in the URI path. But you need to be careful when writing relative URI paths with a colon since it is not allowed when used like this:
>
> ```
> <a href="tag:sample">
> ```
>
> In this case tag would be interpreted as the URI’s scheme. Instead you need to write it like this:
>
> ```
> <a href="./tag:sample">
> ```

#### Usage of `urljoin`

The function `urljoin` simply treats both arguments as URL (without any presumption). It requires that their schemes to be identical or the second one to represent a *relative URI path*. Otherwise, it only returns the second argument (although, IMHO, it should raise an error). You can better understand the logic by looking into the [source of urljoin](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9a3ffc0492d1310ead9ce8f5ee678c26b20a338d/Lib/urllib/parse.py#L493).

```
def urljoin(base, url, allow_fragments=True):
    """Join a base URL and a possibly relative URL to form an absolute
    interpretation of the latter."""
    ...
    bscheme, bnetloc, bpath, bparams, bquery, bfragment = \
            urlparse(base, '', allow_fragments)
    scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = \
            urlparse(url, bscheme, allow_fragments)

    if scheme != bscheme or scheme not in uses_relative:
        return _coerce_result(url)
```

The results of the parser routine `urlparse` are as follow:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('123:abc')
ParseResult(scheme='123', netloc='', path='abc', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('abc:123')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='abc:123', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('abc:a123')
ParseResult(scheme='abc', netloc='', path='a123', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Comment: Sooo... basically what you are saying is: it's rather a problem with `urlparse`, and rather an unfixable one because it deals with sneaky edge cases.

Comment: No. I don't think it's a problem of either `urlparse` or `urljoin`. It's a problem of your usage of them. Please use [urllib.parse.quote](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) to escape colon in your path!