# What format of url is this with the colon almost in the end - https://speech.googleapis.com/v1p1beta1/speech:longrunningrecognize

Tags: url, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to consume the google text to speech api here : https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#speech-async-recognize-gcs-protocol

and it has this url format below

```
 https://google-speech-api-base-urlspeech:longrunningrecognize
```

What is this URL format with colon(:)in the end?

When I try to hit this URL, it gives me an error specifically while running test case on it .e. Invalid URI. Invalid Port?

But the official google documentation says this is a valid url? How to use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This format of URL is called gRPC Transcoding syntax. Your first URL is invlaid , because it's in the first path segment of a relative-path reference.

https://google-speech-api-base-urlspeech:longrunningrecognize

This url is invalid for usage, whereas the one below, https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize           was running fine.

Try changing your URL  to something like
https://google-speech-api-base-url/speech:longrunningrecognize. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the documentation page you referenced and was unable to see/find a URL that looked like:

```
https://google-speech-api-base-urlspeech:longrunningrecognize
```

However, what I did find was a URL of the form:

```
https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize
```

which looks perfectly valid.

The documentation for this REST request can be found here:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/longrunningrecognize

Could you have made an error in your reading and comprehension?

Apparently the colon (`:`) is legal in the path part of a URL:

[Are colons allowed in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737575/are-colons-allowed-in-urls/2579105)