# what does colon ':' mean in URL?

Tags: html, url, uri

for example http://www.wikihow.com/Special:CreatePage

what does the ":" mean between "Special" and "CreatePage"

Comment: No special meaning. The colon is just an allowed character in the path, just like the other characters in the path are. How they are interpreted is up to the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are colons allowed in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737575/are-colons-allowed-in-urls)

Answer (score 0):

> `http://mysite/gwturl#user:91/comment`

All the characters in the [fragment part][2] (`user:45/comments`) are perfectly legal for [RFC 3986][3] URIs.

The relevant parts of the [ABNF][4]:

```
fragment      = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
                 / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

---

### for more Refer this below answer

[Is a colon `:` safe for friendly-URL use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053132/is-a-colon-safe-for-friendly-url-use/2053441#2053441)